# Copy pasting the same code results in an error

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an issue where repeating a specific block of code several times returns the error below.

```
Undefined control sequence.

‪./main.tex, 339‬
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
Learn more
\sl@RemoveGobble ...l@Terminator ->\def \sl@Tempb 
                                                  {#2}\ifx \sl@Tempb \@empty...
l.339 \end{tikzpicture}}
                        \imagehspace
```

This is the code

```
\RequirePackage{silence} % :-\
    \WarningFilter{scrreprt}{Usage of package `titlesec'}
    %\WarningFilter{scrreprt}{Activating an ugly workaround}
    \WarningFilter{titlesec}{Non standard sectioning command detected}
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,%1headlines,
                headinclude,footinclude,cleardoublepage=empty,abstract=on,
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt
                ]{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{
  drafting=false,    % print version information on the bottom of the pages
  tocaligned=false, % the left column of the toc will be aligned (no indentation)
  dottedtoc=true,  % page numbers in ToC flushed right
  eulerchapternumbers=true, % use AMS Euler for chapter font (otherwise Palatino)
  linedheaders=false,       % chaper headers will have line above and beneath
  floatperchapter=true,     % numbering per chapter for all floats (i.e., Figure 1.1)
  eulermath=false,  % use awesome Euler fonts for mathematical formulae (only with pdfLaTeX)
  beramono=true,    % toggle a nice monospaced font (w/ bold)
  palatino=true,    % deactivate standard font for loading another one, see the last section at the end of this file for suggestions
  style=classicthesis % classicthesis, arsclassica
}{classicthesis}

\PassOptionsToPackage{american}{babel}
    \usepackage{babel}

\PassOptionsToPackage{%
  %backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8, %instead of bibtex
  backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=ascii,%
  language=auto,%
  % style=numeric-comp,%
  style=authoryear-comp, % Author 1999, 2010
  %bibstyle=authoryear,dashed=false, % dashed: substitute rep. author with ---
  sorting=nyt, % name, year, title
  maxbibnames=10, % default: 3, et al.
  backref=true,%
  % backrefstyle=all+,%
  % backreffloats=true,%
  natbib=true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
}{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex}

% ********************************************************************
% General useful packages
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} %
\PassOptionsToPackage{printonlyused,smaller}{acronym}
  \usepackage{acronym} % nice macros for handling all acronyms in the thesis
  \def\bflabel#1{{\acsfont{#1}\hfill}}
  \def\aclabelfont#1{\acsfont{#1}}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

%Reduce margins slightly to compensate for double spacing
\usepackage[right=4cm,left=4cm,bottom=3.5cm,top=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

%********************************************************************
% Mainmatter
%*******************************************************
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

% % % % % % %
% AAAI 2024 %
% % % % % % %

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definetrim}[2]{%
  \define@key{Gin}{#1}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{trim=#2,clip}}%
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{multiplealignment}{%
  $$\vbox\bgroup
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{\jot}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \vspace{-\jot}%
}{\egroup$$}

\newcommand{\tsum}{\mathop{\textstyle\sum}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\ubrace}[2]{{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}

\newcommand{\Cbox}[1]{{\color{#1}\rule{2ex}{2ex}}}
\definecolor{no_contact_color}{rgb}{0.396,0.435,0.498}
\definecolor{cucumber_color}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{peeler_color}{rgb}{0.835,0.730,0.632}
\definecolor{bottle_color}{rgb}{1,0.647,0}
\definecolor{cup_color}{rgb}{0,1,0.8117}

\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsred}{O{}m}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.4mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\ht0}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsblue}{O{}m}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.4mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{blue}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\ht0}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsblack}{O{}m}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{black}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\ht0}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsbluetop}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{\dimexpr #3-\ht0\relax}{\usebox{0}}}%
  \textcolor{blue}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsredtop}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{\dimexpr #3-\ht0\relax}{\usebox{0}}}%
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}

%\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
%\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
\definetrim{kit_mocap}{21cm 8.8cm 18cm 1.5cm} % {left bottom right top}
\def\barheight{0.015}
\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}
\def\fingerwidth{0.08\textwidth}
\def\testvar{0.08\textheight}
\def\imagehspace{\hspace{-0.1em}}
\def\imagehspacea{\hspace{-0.2em}}
\def\imagevspace{\vspace{-0.35cm}}
\def\kitmocapfont{\scriptsize}

\newlength{\wantedheight}
\settoheight{\wantedheight}{\includegraphics[width=\fingerwidth,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/fingers/cucumber/gt_43.png}}% For example use this image for the height. Alternatively you can use every height, you want.

\begin{figure*}[t!]
\vspace{0.5cm}
\centering

% % % % %
% % mod %
% % % % %

\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imagea) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/mod/mod_05.png}};
    \begin{scope}[anchor=south west]
        \node[draw,fill=white,rotate=0] at (0,0) {\kitmocapfont{Mod}};
    \end{scope}
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imagea.north west) {\tiny{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (imageb) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/mod/mod_35.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imageb.north west) {\tiny{2}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (imagec) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/mod/mod_43.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imagec.north west) {\tiny{3}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (imaged) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/mod/mod_53.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imaged.north west) {\tiny{4}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (imagee) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/mod/mod_60.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imagee.north west) {\tiny{5}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (imagef) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/mod/mod_68.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imagef.north west) {\tiny{6}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (imageg) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/mod/mod_75.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imageg.north west) {\tiny{7}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (imageh) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/mod/mod_85.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imageh.north west) {\tiny{8}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagevspace

% % % % % %
% fingers %
% % % % % %

\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsbluetop[width=\fingerwidth]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/fingers/cucumber/gt_43.png}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south west,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {\kitmocapfont{GT}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspacea
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsbluetop[width=\fingerwidth,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/fingers/cucumber/mod_43.png}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south west,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {\kitmocapfont{Mod}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspacea
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsbluetop[width=\fingerwidth,trim=0 0cm 0 0,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/fingers/cucumber/ours_43.png}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south west,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {\kitmocapfont{Ours}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspacea
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsbluetop[width=\fingerwidth,trim=0 0cm 0 0,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/fingers/peeler/gt_43_2.png}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south west,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {\kitmocapfont{GT}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspacea
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsbluetop[width=\fingerwidth,trim=0 0cm 0 0,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/fingers/peeler/mod_43_2.png}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south west,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {\kitmocapfont{Mod}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspacea
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsbluetop[width=\fingerwidth,trim=0 0cm 0 0,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/fingers/peeler/ours_43_2.png}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south west,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {\kitmocapfont{Ours}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspacea
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsredtop[width=\fingerwidth,trim=0 0 0 0,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/fingers/cucumber/gt_53.png}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south west,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {\kitmocapfont{GT}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspacea
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsredtop[width=\fingerwidth,trim=0 0cm 0 0,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/fingers/cucumber/mod_53_2.png}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south west,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {\kitmocapfont{Mod}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspacea
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsredtop[width=\fingerwidth,trim=0 0 0 0,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/fingers/cucumber/ours_53.png}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south west,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {\kitmocapfont{Ours}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspacea
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsredtop[width=\fingerwidth,trim=0 0 0 0,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/fingers/peeler/gt_53.png}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south west,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {\kitmocapfont{GT}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspacea
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsredtop[width=\fingerwidth,trim=0 0 0 0,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/fingers/peeler/mod_53.png}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south west,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {\kitmocapfont{Mod}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspacea
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsredtop[width=\fingerwidth,trim=0 0 0 0,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/fingers/peeler/ours_53.png}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south west,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {\kitmocapfont{Ours}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagevspace

% % % % % %
% % ours  % 
% % % % % %

\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image1) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/ours/ours_05.png}};
    \begin{scope}[anchor=south west]
        \node[draw,fill=white,rotate=0] at (0,0) {\kitmocapfont{Ours}};
    \end{scope}
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image1.north west) {\tiny{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image2) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/ours/ours_35.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image2.north west) {\tiny{2}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[inner sep=0] (image3) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/ours/ours_43.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image3.north west) {\tiny{3}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image4) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/ours/ours_53.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image4.north west) {\tiny{4}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image5) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/ours/ours_60.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image5.north west) {\tiny{5}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/ours/ours_68.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image6.north west) {\tiny{6}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image7) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/ours/ours_68.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image7.north west) {\tiny{6}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% % contact classification  %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}rl}   
    \footnotesize{True Left} &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/true_l.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    \footnotesize{Pred Left} &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/pred_l.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    \footnotesize{True Right} &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar3) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/true_r.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    \footnotesize{Pred Right} &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/pred_r.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{tabular}

\label{fig:qualitative_kit_rgbd}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
% ********************************************************************
```

The code runs if I comment out only one block

```
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image7) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{Chapters/AAAI2024/figures/experiments/kit_mocap/ours/ours_68.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image7.north west) {\tiny{6}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
```

or I comment out

```
\RequirePackage{silence} % :-\
    \WarningFilter{scrreprt}{Usage of package `titlesec'}
    %\WarningFilter{scrreprt}{Activating an ugly workaround}
    \WarningFilter{titlesec}{Non standard sectioning command detected}
```

Comment: Well so why don't you comment out the silence package?

Comment: Why didn't you edit your other question about this error? Why ask another one?

Comment: the silence package redefines many latex internals to try to turn off warning messages. It's not clear that this is ever a good idea, but if it works, OK. If it causes errors with a particular construct just don't use the silence package. It's always better not to do whatever tex is warning about, than to do it anyway and silence the warning.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle *Always?*

Comment: @cfr well I've used tex for almost 40 years and never used silence, so in my experience, yes

Comment: Off-topic: Loading `graphicx` with driver options like `pdftex` , `luatex`, `xetex` does not really make sense. These driver options are engine dependent and `graphics.cfg` does auto-detect the correct driver option. Overwriting auto-detect driver options `luatex`, `xetex` or `pdftex`, can even cause harm. Driver options make only sense, if an engine with dvi output is used and the default `dvips` backend should not be used, but e.g. `dvipdfmx`, `dvisvgm`, `emtex` …

Comment: Off-topic: Are you sure, you want to use `bibtex8` instead of `biber` with `biblatex`? With the styles distributed with `biblatex` this usually isn't a problem (at least with English), but it is not perfect and some `biblatex` features even need `biber`. So switching to `biber` is IMHO recommended. Several month ago, `biber` was a problem when using an ARM linux. But meanwhile linux-aarch64 is also supported.

Comment: The silence package is defined in the overleaf thesis template of my school so I would prefer not to remove what is included.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I misread your final sentence and missed the 'and ...' part. I wouldn't use `silence`.

Comment: @Kong Unless the template in question is maintained by somebody who knows what they're doing and has the resources to support it, it is likely to cause you many problems. If you're fortunate enough to be somewhere where that doesn't apply, report the problem to the maintainer and link this thread. The very fact the template uses `silence` suggests you are not in that happy (and highly unusual) situation. You are using a template which loads combinations of packages known to cause problems and suppresses those packages' attempts to warn you about this. Your policy is a millstone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example can be reduce to this one:

```
\RequirePackage{silence} 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{subfigure}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}}
\setcounter{subfigure}{27}
\makeatletter \protected@edef\blub{\thesubfigure} \makeatother
xxx
\end{document}
```

This compiles without the `silence` package but errors if you use it as it redefines the LaTeX error messages in a way that no longer is safe in a \protected@edef.

In your document it errors because you have 26 subfloats and the caption package set the counter to 27 in preparation for the next one. `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}` would work.

Personally I wouldn't use the silence package.